# How to query aggregate max, min, median latitude of polygons in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I am just starting to learn how to use PostGIS (1.5.4) and my SQL skills are essentially those of a competent beginner. Having perused the PostGIS documentation and searched these forums, I'm not finding the answers to what are surely some very simple questions.

Given a single table loaded with polygons from shapefiles, how can I query the latitudinal maximum and minimum and the centroids of single and aggregate rows? I'll note that I have found the ST_Centroid() function, but haven't figured out how to interpret its output (CRS=WGS84).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maximum latitude for one row:

```
osm=# select st_ymax(way) from planet_osm_polygon where name = 'Sector 1';
  st_ymax   
------------
 5549655.89
(1 row)
```

maximum latitude over aggregate:

```
osm=# select max(st_ymax(way)) from planet_osm_polygon where name in ('Sector 1', 'Sector 2');
    max     
------------
 5549655.89
(1 row)
```

Centroid in human readable form:

```
osm=# select st_asewkt(st_centroid(way)) from planet_osm_polygon where name = 'Sector 1';
                      st_asewkt                      
-----------------------------------------------------
 SRID=900913;POINT(2901008.17035358 5541774.5761637)
(1 row)
```

Centroid reprojected to EPSG 4326 (WGS84) in human readable form:

```
osm=# select st_asewkt(st_centroid(st_transform(way, 4326))) from planet_osm_polygon where name = 'Sector 1';
                     st_asewkt                      
----------------------------------------------------
 SRID=4326;POINT(26.0602007930189 44.4911898194805)
(1 row)
```

"Centroid of aggregate rows" I'm not sure how to read.
You can aggregate geometries by using `st_union` and then compute the centroid of the aggregated geometry:

```
osm=# select st_astext(st_centroid(st_union(way))) from planet_osm_polygon where name in ('Sector 1', 'Sector 2');
                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(2903674.04223639 5540178.39415804)
(1 row)
```

Later edit: If median latitude is the average of minimum and maximum latitude, I don't think `st_centroid` is guaranteed to be equal to it. If you require average latitude, you can just compute `(st_ymax(way) + st_ymin(way))/2`.

Comment: Thanks! The function ST_AsEWKT() to return "as well known text" was just what I needed to make sense of the centroid data. What I meant by an aggregate centroid is a point that may fall outside of any of the polygons being queried, the first moment or center of balance of the aggregated polygons on the spheroid's surface.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [standard aggregate functions for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). The typical ones are min, avg, max, but there are many others. Median is not supplied by default, but [you can add it](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median), then use `median(something::numeric)` to use it (similar to where you see `avg(something)` below).

ST_Centroid is good for getting an estimate for the middle, but for the top/bottom coordinates from each polygon, you can use [ST_Ymin](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_YMin.html) and [ST_Ymax](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_YMax.html). Here is a typical aggregate:

```
SELECT min(ST_Ymin(geom)), avg(ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom))), max(ST_Ymax(geom))
FROM my_table;
```

You should get one row. If you want to get fancier, and group them by some other classification:

```
SELECT category, min(ST_Ymin(geom)), avg(ST_Y(ST_Centroid(geom))), max(ST_Ymax(geom))
FROM my_table
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category;
```

Should show the min/avg/max latitudes for each category. Aggregate fun!

Comment: Very helpful. I suspect I'll be using the ST_Y() and ST_Ymin/max functions a lot in the coming weeks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is 8 years too late, but the above answers may pre-date PostGIS' implementation of [St_GeometricMedian](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometricMedian.html).

Here's a working example that unions every centroid of features in a given table and finds the median:

```
with b as (select st_centroid(geom) as geom from geo_table)

select 
ST_GeometricMedian(st_union(geom)) as median_centroid_wkb,
ST_AsText(ST_GeometricMedian(st_union(geom))) as median_centroid_wkt,
from b
```